# Cannot import another python file in directory

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to import another python file into a program. This is my directory structure:

```
+root<br>
|-- train.py<br>
|--+src<br>
|    |--layers.py
|    |--mccnn.py
```

Currently my `train.py` file uses this

```
import src.mccnn as mccnn
import src.layers as L
```

And the `mccnn.py` file uses

```
import layers as L
```

When I run `test.py`, I run into an error "No module named 'layers', and in the traceback I can see its raised  in the `mccnn.py` file

I'm running the python file in root folder. I can't figure out why this is throwing an error. None of the answers I could find helped solve the issue. 
*PS: the original code was written for Python 2.7. Not sure if its relevant information.*

Answer (score 0):

Follow the structure as

```
+root
|-- 
|----src
|------<package_name>
|         |--__init__.py
|         |--layers.py
|         |--mccnn.py
|         |--train.py<br>
```

Then say in mccnn.py you can just say 
`import layers as L` 
and in train.py you can say

```
import mccnn as mccnn
import layers as L
```

More details can be seen here https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/

Comment: I need train.py to be in the root folder because all my path names are defined according to that